# Why does laravel get an application error

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, runtime-error, homestead

In the windows 10 operating system I installed a homestead laravel for project deployment.

After I worked in a vagrant homestead virtual machine, I ran the command `vagrand halt`

The next day I launched a homestate with the command `vagrant up`

I connected via SSH to the homestead virtual machine, enter the command `php artisan` and get the error:

> In LoadConfiguration.php line 68:
>
> Unable to load the "app" configuration file.

When opening the site, the error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/vagrant/code/projects/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234
>
> RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/vagrant/code/projects/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234

Answer (score 3):

This has already been solved, on GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1219

Try upgrading to VM 6.

*Update*

1. Download and install the latest version of vagrant:
   https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
2. Updating homestead:

`vagrant global-status`

This will list all your vagrant boxes with box name in the 2nd column

`vagrant box update "{box_name}"`

3. Download and install the latest VM: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

   **Here you may need to uninstall the old version at first**

Comment: This answer might be more useful with a link to instructions on upgrading. I confess to having used Homestead for two years without any idea on how to upgrade it.